# PHP cURL content type not set

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, dropbox

I am using `cURL` to make `dropbox` `REST API` call. Here is what I am doing:

```
$service_url = 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/create_folder';
$curl = curl_init();
$curl_post_data = array(
    'path' => '/ehsan/malik',
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Bearer ********accesstoken*********'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curl_post_data));
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);



if ($curl_response === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    die('<br>error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
}
curl_close($curl);
$decoded = json_decode($curl_response);
if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
    die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
}
echo 'response ok!';
var_export($decoded->response);
```

And when the script runs, this is what `$info` returnes:

```
> array ( 'url' => 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/create_folder',
> 'content_type' => NULL, 'http_code' => 0, 'header_size' => 0,
> 'request_size' => 0, 'filetime' => -1, 'ssl_verify_result' => 1,
> 'redirect_count' => 0, 'total_time' =>
> 0.717000000000000081712414612411521375179290771484375, 'namelookup_time' =>
> 0.12399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375, 'connect_time' =>
> 0.4210000000000000408562073062057606875896453857421875, 'pretransfer_time' => 0, 'size_upload' => 0, 'size_download' => 0,
> 'speed_download' => 0, 'speed_upload' => 0, 'download_content_length'
> => -1, 'upload_content_length' => -1, 'starttransfer_time' => 0, 'redirect_time' => 0, 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' =>
> '108.160.172.205', 'certinfo' => array ( ), 'primary_port' => 443,
> 'local_ip' => '192.168.1.234', 'local_port' => 9306, ) error occured
> during curl exec.
```

Additional info:

Here the content type is showed `null` in the `error` but I am setting it to be `application/json` while making the call. What am I missing? How to get it right?

Comment: To get the correct curl error you should use `die('<br>error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: '. curl_error($curl));`

Comment: You have to call `curl_error($curl)` before `curl_close($curl)`

Comment: okay, I did that and this is the error: "curl_error(): 2 is not a valid cURL handle resource in D:\xampp\htdocs\centrify\index.php on line 21"

Comment: This is the kind of error you get when you call curl_error on an invalid handle. Are you sure you called curl_error before closing curl instance?

Comment: okay, I called rurl_error at the very last of my code and the error is gone. When I do this `echo $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)`, I get `0`. Is `0` is http code or API related thing?

Comment: And when I print `$info`, it gives `content-type` as an empty string, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing JSONification on your POST data:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
```

and remove `'Content-Type: application/json'` header. Let cURL to manage headers for you.

Comment: tried it but the same results. content-type is still null.